# How to call WSADuplicateSocket from the target process?

Tags: sockets, winapi

My program needs to send a packet to all sockets opened in any aim program.

I can know their socket handles, but I need to duplicate them in order to use them in my process.

`WSADuplicateSocket` is used to duplicate handles (which retrieves `LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFO lpProtocolInfo` which has to be used to create a new socket in other process), but it apparently must be called from the source program.

Is there a way to get the the correct `LPWSAPROTOCOL_INFO lpProtocolInfo` to copy the socket as I were calling that function from other process?

I already tried other way, using `DuplicateHandle` instead of `WSADuplicateSocket`:

```
HANDLE source_handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, PID);
HANDLE newhandle;

DuplicateHandle(source_handle, (HANDLE)olds,
    GetCurrentProcess(), &newhandle, 0, FALSE,
    DUPLICATE_CLOSE_SOURCE | DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);
```

but it doesn't seems to work.

Comment: I don't see an easy way. A socket handle is local to the process that created it. That's why you must pass the target process id to WSADuplicateSocket.

Comment: Only the source process can call `WSADuplicateSocket()` and only the target process can call `WSASocket()` to use the duplicated socket.

Comment: IOW, you'll have to use code injection.  But the whole thing sounds like a really bad idea to me.